# Open and close a div with include others files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page

**master.html**

with these scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.art').click(function() {var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#contentart').load(url);
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: parseInt($('#contentart').offset().top)}, 'slow');
        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $("#contentart").slideToggle();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the body:

```
<div class="one">
<a class="art" href="file1.html">link</a>
<a class="art" href="file2.html">link</a>
<a class="art" href="file3.html">link</a>
<a class="art" href="file4.html">link</a>
ecc ecc
</div>
```

and with the click on these links opens the relative file file_.html in this div:

```
<div style="width: 100%" id="contentart"></div>
```

with a soft moviment to the div contentart

in the body I have this link

```
<a href="#qui"cursor: pointer;" class="show_hide">close the div</a>
```

for a new chose; this function closes the div and goes up the top .

But all the function doesn't works well: is slow for open, if I open the second time the link (ALTRO) doesn't open the new.
Here the test link:

http://vangelodelre.it/test/files/contenuti.html

Please I need a help for repair all because I am not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

It's slow, because you are not loading just the text, but also a bunch of stylessheets and other things that dont belong in the body at all.

You are even forcing a reload of jquery (that's HUGE). Check what happens when you click the links in FireBug network console.

[image]

All the GETs are sent after you click a link. I don't understand fully your code, there's alot of obfuscated code, but something is seriously wrong with it.